# How can I find all object not equal to array of ids from mongo db using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used this code but it gave me an error

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ '$ne': [ '5d672f79b549f613faf677ce', '5d685bb91a8bcd04000bf7ae' ] }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Class\""

```
const relatedClsQuery = await Class.find({_id:{$in:{$ne:['5d672f79b549f613faf677ce', '5d685bb91a8bcd04000bf7ae']}}},'id subject');
```

Please explain to me what is the best solution for these kinds of situations.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching, I found this solution provide by Mongo DB.

```
const relatedClsQuery = await Class.find({_id:{$nin:['5d672f79b549f613faf677ce', '5d685bb91a8bcd04000bf7ae']}},'_id subject');
```